# Доработка проги перемножение двух матриц

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется html документ и подключенный к ней js, но почему-то не работает кнопка умножения, хотя функция рабочая,подскажите пожалуйста
Сам код

```js
var A = function() {
  $('.matrix_a').find('input');
};
var b = function() {
  $('.matrix_b').find('input');
};

function MultiplyMatrix(A, B) {
  var rowsA = A.length,
    colsA = A[0].length,
    rowsB = B.length,
    colsB = B[0].length,
    C = [];
  if (colsA != rowsB) return false;
  for (var i = 0; i < rowsA; i++) C[i] = [];
  for (var k = 0; k < colsB; k++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rowsA; i++) {
      var t = 0;
      for (var j = 0; j < rowsB; j++) t += A[i][j] * B[j][k];
      C[i][k] = t;
    }
    console.log('check code')
  }

  console.log(C);
  return C;
}
$(document).on('click', '.umn', function() {
  MultiplyMatrix();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style_matrix.css">
  <script src="matrices.js"></script>
  <div class="left-side">
    <button class="umn">umn</button>
    <br>
    <div class="add_mtrx">
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main_cover">

    <div class="matrix_a_cover">
      <table class="matrix_a brackets" id="matrix_a">

        <tr>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="a1,1">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="a1,2">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="a1,3">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="a2,1">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="a2,2">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="a2,3">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="a3,1">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="a3,2">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="a3,3">
          </td>
        </tr>


      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="matrix_b_cover">
      <table class="matrix_b brackets" id="matrix_b">

        <tr>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="b1,1">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="b1,2">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="b1,3">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="b2,1">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="b2,2">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="b2,3">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="b3,1">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="b3,2">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="b3,3">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>


    <div class="matrix_c_cover">
      <table class="matrix_c brackets">

        <tr>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c1,1">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c1,2">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c1,3">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c2,1">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c2,2">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c2,3">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c3,1">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c3,2">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c3,3">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Не стал вникать, но замечу что у вас маленькое var b вместо заглавного B во второй функции *

Comment: Исправил, но кнопка не фурычит

Comment: _"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"_

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.umn', function() {
  var mA = ...; // create and fill first matrix 
  var mB = ...; // create and fill second matrix 
  var mC = MultiplyMatrix(mA, mB);
  // put values from matrix mC into inputs
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция `MultiplyMatrix` ожидает на вход два двухмерных массива. Вы же в нее ничего не передаете. С вероятностью в 90% эту функцию писали не вы сами)

Посмотрите пример, в нем правильно вызывается данная функция.

```js
function MultiplyMatrix(A, B) {
  var rowsA = A.length,
    colsA = A[0].length,
    rowsB = B.length,
    colsB = B[0].length,
    C = [];
  if (colsA != rowsB) return false;
  for (var i = 0; i < rowsA; i++) C[i] = [];
  for (var k = 0; k < colsB; k++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rowsA; i++) {
      var t = 0;
      for (var j = 0; j < rowsB; j++) t += A[i][j] * B[j][k];
      C[i][k] = t;
    }
  }

  console.log(C);
  return C;
}

function tableToMatrix(table) {
  return [...table.querySelectorAll('tr')].map(tr => [...tr.querySelectorAll('input')].map(m => m.value * 1));
}
$(document).on('click', '.umn', function() {
  var a = tableToMatrix(document.querySelector('.matrix_a'));
  var b = tableToMatrix(document.querySelector('.matrix_b'));
  MultiplyMatrix(a, b);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style_matrix.css">
  <script src="matrices.js"></script>
  <div class="left-side">
    <button class="umn">umn</button>
    <br>
    <div class="add_mtrx">
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main_cover">

    <div class="matrix_a_cover">
      <table class="matrix_a brackets" id="matrix_a">

        <tr>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="a1,1">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="a1,2">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="a1,3">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="a2,1">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="a2,2">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="a2,3">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="a3,1">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="a3,2">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="a3,3">
          </td>
        </tr>


      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="matrix_b_cover">
      <table class="matrix_b brackets" id="matrix_b">

        <tr>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="b1,1">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="b1,2">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="b1,3">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="b2,1">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="b2,2">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="b2,3">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="b3,1">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="b3,2">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" placeholder="b3,3">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>


    <div class="matrix_c_cover">
      <table class="matrix_c brackets">

        <tr>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c1,1">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c1,2">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c1,3">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c2,1">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c2,2">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c2,3">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c3,1">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c3,2">
          </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
            <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c3,3">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```